# Is it possible to recognize devices connected via Bluetooth through an OpenvSwitch

Tags: networking, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, openvswitch

I have a raspberry pi on which I have installed an openvswitch. The raspberry pi has Bluetooth on it. The openvswitch is connected to an Opendaylight controller.

When I connect the raspberry pi to the network, I am able to see that the controller recognizes those devices. I can also connect other devices to the raspberry pi through an Ethernet cable, configure interfaces on the raspberry pi and the controller recognizes those devices. Now I am trying to do the same with devices connected via Bluetooth. Is there a way to do that?

PS. I tried looking into Bluetooth PAN. Would that be the way to go?

Comment: How does the Bluetooth interface appear in Linux? Is that another interface in ifconfig/ip a with a different type?

Comment: @pchaigno the bluetooth interface is completely separate. From what I understand if I setup Bluetooth PAN, it will be another interface in ifconfig/ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to [connect Bluetooth devices to a Linux bridge](https://superuser.com/a/1062963/775055). You could then connect that Linux bridge to Open vSwitch with a veth. Devices connected via Bluetooth will have to speak Ethernet over Bluetooth though.

To create the veth pair and connect it to both ends:

```
ip link add veth-linux type veth peer name veth-ovs
ovs-vsctl add-br br-int
ovs-vsctl add-port br-int veth-ovs
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 veth-linux
```